# How do I tell if a question has been reviewed after it has been flagged as a duplicate?

Tags: support, review-queues, questions

I asked a question which was flagged as duplicate: [Validate a YAML file based on a JSON schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802732/how-do-i-validate-a-yaml-file-based-on-a-json-schema)
I did an update to differentiate it from the flagged duplicate.
How can I tell if it's been reviewed since the change?

Comment: Check the timeline https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54802732/timeline

Comment: Wow what a terrible duplicate closure. Question is "I have a schema, how do I use it to validate?" and the duplicate is "Can I somehow validate?" (answer is 'yes you can validate by generating a schema in language x, y, or z.') That being said I would have closed as 'too broad' because there's probably a dozen ways of doing it.

Comment: Note, however, that the timeline only shows an entry for reviews once the post exits the review queue (i.e. after all necessary reviews of that type are completed). It does not show reviews that are in process.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Your comment, regardless of it's content, is pretty rude. Adding your disbelief at the (in your opinion) "terrible" choice doesn't add any value to an otherwise valuable comment...  I'd encourage reposting minus the charged language.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty - It seems like the best reason to close as too broad. If there are six answers, and they're all valid, which one gets marked correct? It would be more focused (eg less broad) if it were something like "I have some yaml, and some schema, and I know I should be able to validate it using tool xyz, and i've tried <this> but it doesn't work." But instead, the tool and the attempt are left as solutions for the reader. Thus it seems too broad.

Comment: @TemporalWolf - Sorry, no matter how I reread my comment do I get any "rudeness" from it. I pointed out that the two questions are fundamentally different (how do I vs can I) and then I put my opinion (not a dupe, but too broad.) My opinion is the least important part of it, actually, and only an afterthought (I edited the comment to add it.). Either way feel free to flag it and tell the mods you were offended, that's your right.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I was speaking *only* of the first sentence... it's dismissive of the person who closed it as a dupe. It doesn't add any constructive information over "I disagree with the dupe target:" but includes your incredulity at their "terrible" closure... which I'd say is unkind. You're of course welcome to disagree, but is that more clear?

Comment: @TemporalWolf - Not really. It implies that I'm not allowed to have an opinion if it is negative. The only alternatives I can think of to use instead of 'terrible' are 'apalling', 'dreadful', or 'atrocious', none of which seem any "nicer". How would *you* go about saying "this is a terrible choice of duplicate for a closure"?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas "This shouldn't have been duped, as the dupe target doesn't address the question: [reasons]" The comment stands without it. How might you react if someone posted, in response to your comment "Wow, what a terrible comment. [reasons]" It's accusative and doesn't add anything over "I disagree for [reasons]."

Comment: @TemporalWolf - Honestly? I wouldn't care if you called my comment terrible, horrible, no-good, very-bad, and so on. This is the internet, this is normal. I'm not disagreeing that the question shouldn't be closed as a dupe -- perhaps there's an *actual* question that matches the OP's -- but I'm saying that the choice of the dupe target is bad.